# Detect touch on specific layer independently

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a main layer. and in that there are 9 child layer add.
e.g a main layer of board and added 9 layers of squares.

I want to detect touch on specific location.

But it detect only for 1st one. Plzz Help me to solvi ti.

```
Here is a some code.
//
//  Board.m
//  Tic Tac Toe
//
//  Created by Waqas Naseem on 8/23/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

    #import "Board.h"


    @implementation Board

    @synthesize squares;

    - (id)init
    {

        self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255) width:300 height:300];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code here.
            index=0;


            for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {

                [self addSquare];
            }





        }

        return self;
    }

    -(void)addSquare
    {

        Square *square=[[Square node] retain];        
        [square setPosition:ccp((index%3)*100, (index/3)*100)];
        //[square setPosition:ccp(100, 0)];
        [self addChild:square];
        index++;
    }
    -(BOOL)isTouchEnabled
    {
        return YES;
    }
    -(void)setIsTouchEnabled:(BOOL)isTouchEnabled
    {

    }

    -(void)squaretouched
    {
        NSLog(@"Square touched");
    }
    @end


    @implementation Square

    @synthesize state;

    -(id)init
    {
        self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255) width:100 height:100];

        if(self)
        {
            isTouchEnabled_=YES;
            //[self setRotation:30];

            CCSprite *square=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"square.png"];

            xImg=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"myCross.png"];

            oImg=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"myO.png"];



            [square setPosition:ccp(50, 50)];

            [xImg setPosition:ccp(50, 50)];

            [oImg setPosition:ccp(50, 50)];

            [xImg setVisible:NO];

            [self addChild:square];

            [self addChild:xImg];
            [self addChild:oImg];

            [self setOpacity:255];




        }
        return self;
    }



    -(BOOL)handleTouch:(CGPoint)location
    {
        NSLog(@"Me touched ");
        return YES;
    }

    @end

    And this is the TouchLayerColor class

    //
    //  TouchAbleColorLayer.m
    //  Tic Tac Toe
    //
    //  Created by Waqas Naseem on 8/24/12.
    //  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "TouchAbleColorLayer.h"

    @implementation TouchAbleColorLayer

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code here.
        }

        return self;
    }
    -(CGRect) rect
    {
        float h=[self contentSize].height;
        float w=[self contentSize].width;

        //convert to origional locaiton

        CGPoint pos=[self convertToWorldSpace:CGPointZero];

        //CGPoint pos=[self convertToNodeSpace:CGPointZero];

        //CGPoint pos=ccp(50, 100);

        float x=pos.x;
        float y=pos.y;

        return  CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    }
    -(BOOL)handleTouch:(CGPoint)location
    {
        // dont hanle touch here
        return NO;
    }

    -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSLog(@"Coming in Touch");
        if(!self.visible || !self.isTouchEnabled)
        {
            NSLog(@"Coming in Touch if");
            return ;
        }
        UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];

        //convert the touch location from uikit to OpenGL Coordinates

        location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

        // did touch Happen in our rectangle ?

        if(CGRectContainsPoint([self rect], location))
        {
            [self handleTouch:location];
        }


    } 

    @end
```

When i click on any square touch method for 9 square is called at once .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got your question. Anyway you may detect the touch in the layer and, in the touch handler, iterate over the list of children and pass the touch position to each child. Of course your children classes shall all implement a common interface with the invoked method (i.e. detectedTouch). This is pretty much like a chain of reponsibility pattern http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern